# Memory leak with string arrays in c

Tags: c, string, memory-leaks, realloc

```
char **add_string(char **existing, const char *string){
  size_t size = 0;
  while (NULL != existing[size]) 
    {
      ++size; 
    }
  char **arr = realloc(existing, (size + 2) * sizeof *arr);
  arr[size] = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
  strcpy(arr[size], string);  
  arr[size+1] = '\0';
  return arr;
}

void free_strings(char **strings)
{
  size_t size = 0;
  while (NULL != strings[size]) 
  {
    free(strings[size]);
    ++size;
  }
}
```

I am having a memory leak at line

```
char **arr = realloc(existing, (size + 2) * sizeof *arr);
```

I thought existing memory was suppose to be free'd when using realloc?  How do I fix this memory leak?

edit: added my free_string function and the main I am using to run the program.

Comment: Where's the code that frees the array later?  A leak-checking tool might point you to the place leaked memory was allocated, but it can't show you where it should be freed... which is what's likely missing.  Provided `realloc()` succeeded, it would either give you the same block or free the old one and allocate a new one... but you still have to free the new (or reused) one at some point later on.

Comment: Why are you doing (size+2) instead of (size+1)?

Comment: @odin the way he gets the size doesn't include the final NULL pointer... so he has to add 2, 1 for the NULL and 1 for the new string.  Although he should be setting that last pointer to `NULL` instead of `'\0'`

Comment: @Dmitri I added my freeing function and the main I am using.

Comment: Your freeing function frees the strings in your array, but not the outer array itself... which is why it's leaked.  Adding `free(strings);` to the end should fix it.

Comment: @Dmitri Thanks, that solved it.  Didn't know I had to free the array itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not append the array pointed to by the pointer `existing` with null pointer. Thus in this loop

while (NULL != existing[size]) 
    {
      ++size; 
    }

the function has undefined behavior.

It seems you mean the following

```
char ** add_string( char **existing, const char *string )
{
    size_t size = 0;

    while ( NULL != existing[size] ) ++size; 

    char **arr = realloc( existing, ( size + 2 ) * sizeof *arr );

    if ( arr != NULL )
    {
        arr[size] = malloc( strlen( string ) + 1 );
        strcpy( arr[size], string );  
        arr[size+1] = NULL;
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Also the function `free_strings` is incorrect. It should look like

```
void free_strings( char **strings )
{
    size_t size` = 0;

    do
    {
        free( strings[size] );
    } while ( strings[size++] != NULL );

    free( strings );
}
```

Comment: I need to realloc size+2 because I have to have room for arr[size] and arr[size+1]

Comment: Thanks, I never free'd the actual strings itself.

Comment: @RoomMates I do not see where you need to add two elements instead of one because you insert only one string.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The value of `size` is obtained by counting the non-NULL `char` pointers, so it's the number of strings -- not the full length of the array (doesn't include the final `NULL` pointer).  He needs room for one more string, plus the final `NULL`... so he adds 2 to `size`.